# Prove that $r_1s_1, r_2s_2, ..., r_{p-1}s_{p-1}$ is not a reduced residue system modulo p.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

If $r_1, ... r_{p-1}$ and $s_1, ... s_{p-1}$ are two reduced residue systems modulo an odd prime p, prove that $r_1s_1, r_2s_2, ..., r_{p-1}s_{p-1}$ is not a reduced residue system modulo p.

don't know where to start, any help appreciated!

Comment: [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: If you don't know where to start, consider special cases. Like the first odd prime would be $p=3$, write down a few examples of reduced residue systems module 3 and look at what your product system looks like.

Comment: Wilson's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

We can permute the $r$-values so that the $r$-system is exactly $1,2,3,\dots,(p-1)$. Using a [theorem of Wilson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), the product of the elements in the given systems are modulo $p$:

$$
(-1)=(p-1)!=\prod_k r_k=\prod_k s_k\mod p\ ,
$$
but 
$$
\prod_k (r_ks_k)=\left(\prod_k r_k\right)\left(\prod_k s_k\right)=(-1)(-1)=1\mod p\ ,
$$
so $(r_ks_k)_k$ is not a reduced system modulo p.